# SQL Max value per Attribute value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen several posts on SO referring to selecting the max value in an attribute grouped by another attribute, but I have been unable to replicate the results and i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

I receive a SQL exception that refers me to check the manual for my version of SQL (Using MySQL).

**Relations**

- User (UID, UName, State)
- Song (SID, AID, SName, ReleaseDate)
- Artist (AID, AName, Description)
- Record (SID, UID, Date)

**I am trying to `SELECT` the User ID and most played song (by name) of 2018.** My attempt is below.

My rationale was to get the relation grouped by User ID (`UID`) and each song by song ID (`SID`) and the count for each song and then join the song names and filter for the `MAX` value, but I'm missing something major here and comparing my answer against the other SO posts relation to something similar hasn't helped much

```
SELECT UID, SName
FROM 
(SELECT UID, SName, COUNT(listenDate) AS listen_date_count
    FROM record
    LEFT JOIN song ON song.SID = record.SID
    WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2018
    GROUP BY UID, SName) AS records_2018
GROUP BY UID, SName
HAVING MAX(listen_date_count);
```

Comment: Can you please tell us which version of MySQL you are using ?

Comment: I was using 5.5

Comment: "I was using 5.5" And `now()` ? Use `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: "I am trying to SELECT the User ID and most played song (by name) of 2018." that suggests you want to have one record as result? Your SQL code does not match that?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good start to do the aggregation by user/song tuples in the subquery. I would simply add a `NOT EXISTS` condition that ensures that there is no other tuple with a highest view count.

The following query should give you the highest viewed song for each user in 2018 :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT r.UID, r.SID, s.SName, COUNT(*) AS listen_date_count
    FROM record r
    INNER JOIN song s ON s.SID = r.SID
    WHERE YEAR(r.Date) = 2018
    GROUP BY r.UID, r.SID, s.SName
) x WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM record r1
    WHERE YEAR(r1.Date) = 2018 AND r1.UID = x.UID AND r1.SID != x.SID
    GROUP BY r1.UID, r1.SID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > x.listen_date_count
)
```

PS :

- you need `SID` in the group by clauses ; grouping by `SName` instead is unsafe, since two different songs having the same name would end up wrongly grouped together
- when using joins or correlated subqueries, you want to prefix the column names with the relevant table prefix. This avoids clashes and generally makes things easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: "This avoids clashes and generally makes things easier to understand and maintain." Unless you need to use EXPLAIN, then you can backtrack all those short alias descriptions in the EXPLAIN table columns back to your SQL code and finding out which short alias is which table.. One off the reasons why use always use fully quantified table names in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can first [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) for the songs only.

Then for that top 1 song, LIMIT for the top user.

```
SELECT usermost.UID, song.SName
FROM
(
   SELECT songmost.SID, rec.UID
   FROM
   (
      SELECT SID
      FROM record 
      WHERE YEAR(`Date`) = 2018
      GROUP BY SID
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, COUNT(DISTINCT UID) DESC
      LIMIT 1
  ) songmost
  JOIN record rec 
    ON rec.SID = songmost.SID AND YEAR(rec.`Date`) = 2018
  GROUP BY rec.SID, rec.UID
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
) usermost
LEFT JOIN song ON song.SID = usermost.SID
```

**Example:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user (
>   UID int primary key not null auto_increment, 
>   UName varchar(30) not null, 
>   State int not null default 0
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE artist (
>   AID int primary key not null auto_increment, 
>   AName varchar(30) not null, 
>   Description  varchar(300)
> );
> ```

> ```
> create table song (
>   SID int primary key not null auto_increment, 
>   AID int not null,
>   SName varchar(30) not null, 
>   ReleaseDate date not null,
>   constraint fk_song_aid foreign key (AID) references artist(AID)
> );
> ```

> ```
> create table record (
>   SID int not null, 
>   UID int not null, 
>   `Date` date not null,
>   constraint fk_record_sid foreign key (SID) references song(SID)
> );
> ```

> ```
> insert into user (UName, State) values 
> ('John Doe', 0), 
> ('Jane Sheppard', 1);
> ```

> ```
> insert into artist (AName, Description) values 
> ('Imagine Dragons', 'American pop rock band'),
> ('Yuki Kajiura', 'Japanese musician, composer and record producer');
> ```

> ```
> insert into song (AID, SName, ReleaseDate) values
> (1, 'Whatever it takes', '2017-10-06'),
> (2, 'I talk to the rain', '2005-07-05');
> ```

> ```
> insert into  record (SID, UID, `Date`) values 
> (1,1,'2018-01-01'),(1,1,'2018-02-01'),(1,2,'2018-03-01'),
> (2,1,'2018-04-01'),(2,2,'2018-01-01');
> ```

> ```
> select rec.SID, song.SName, user.UName, artist.AName, COUNT(*) As Total
> from record rec
> left join song on song.SID = rec.SID
> left join user on user.UID = rec.UID
> left join artist on artist.AID = song.AID
> group by rec.SID, rec.UID
> ```
>
> ```
> SID | SName              | UName         | AName           | Total
> --: | :----------------- | :------------ | :-------------- | ----:
>   1 | Whatever it takes  | John Doe      | Imagine Dragons |     2
>   1 | Whatever it takes  | Jane Sheppard | Imagine Dragons |     1
>   2 | I talk to the rain | John Doe      | Yuki Kajiura    |     1
>   2 | I talk to the rain | Jane Sheppard | Yuki Kajiura    |     1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT usermost.UID, song.SName
> FROM
> (
>    SELECT songmost.SID, rec.UID
>    FROM
>    (
>       SELECT SID
>       FROM record 
>       WHERE YEAR(`Date`) = 2018
>       GROUP BY SID
>       ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, COUNT(DISTINCT UID) DESC
>       LIMIT 1
>   ) songmost
>   JOIN record rec 
>     ON rec.SID = songmost.SID AND YEAR(rec.`Date`) = 2018
>   GROUP BY rec.SID, rec.UID
>   ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
>   LIMIT 1
> ) usermost
> LEFT JOIN song ON song.SID = usermost.SID
> ```
>
> ```
> UID | SName            
> --: | :----------------
>   1 | Whatever it takes
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f9a9b1f637073561afa66b2709f4b73)*